# Splitting complex exponentials

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

Consider $e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}}$. Using exponent rules, translating to $x+iy$ form and simplifying gives:

$$ e^{-i \frac{\pi}{2}} = e^{-1}e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}} = e^{-1} (0+i) = \frac{i}{e}$$

On the other hand,

$$ e^{-i \frac{\pi}{2}} = (0 - i) = -i $$

Therefore,

$$ \frac{i}{e} = -i \implies \frac{1}{e} = -1 $$

Where is the faulty step and why is it faulty?

Comment: For any  $$\;x\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x\implies e^{-\pi i/2}=\cos\frac\pi2-i\sin\frac\pi2=-i\;\ldots$$ And BTW: even in the reals, it is **not true** that $\;a^{xy}=a^xa^y\;$ , with $\;a>0\;$...!

Comment: Your error is in the first equals sign. $e^{-i\frac\pi2}=\bigl(e^{i\frac\pi2}\bigr)^{-1}$, while $e^{-1}e^{i\frac\pi2}=e^{i\frac\pi2-1}$.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ah right you are.

Answer (score 3):

It's wrong from the start. What makes you think that$$e^{-i\frac\pi2}=e^{-1}e^{i\frac\pi2}?$$